# Find element in array using array-includes from npm

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I go about finding the index or element in an array that contains 
something I'm looking for?

When I tried using `includes()` i get

> m.includes() is not a function

I've installed `array-includes` from NPM but I still can't figure out how to 
do it.
Example of what I want:

```
Make an array of strings eg. ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi']
Check each of the elements for If they contain 'orange'
Have it return either the element itself, or the index of the element in the 
array.
```

I've tried:

```
pinmsgs = pinmsgs.filter(includes(pinmsgs, 'countdownTill'))
```

And this is the error:

```
(node:3256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fn is not a function
at Map.filter (C:\Users\oof\Desktop\VVbot - kopie (2) - kopie\node_modules\d
iscord.js\src\util\Collection.js:289:11)
at message.guild.channels.find.fetchPinnedMessages.then (C:\Users\oof\Deskto
p\VVbot - kopie (2) - kopie\bot.js:54:37)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I also need it to work for when i put in only a part of what I'm looking for - eg. if I look for appl it will still output apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you want to find the element. Or [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) if you want to find the index

```js
const array = ['apple', 'orange', 'kiwi'],
      item = "orange";

const found = array.find(a => a.includes(item))
const index = array.findIndex(a => a.includes(item))

// if you want to find if item exists in the array
const fullMatchIndex = array.indexOf(item)

console.log(found)
console.log(index)
console.log(fullMatchIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of function you can use

- Using `indexOf`, returns the index or -1 if not found

```
const a = ['orange', 'apple', 'kiwi'];
console.log(a.indexOf('apple'));
// 1
```

- You can use `filter` to return array of item that matches certain condition

```
const a = ['orange', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'apple'];
console.log(a.filter(x => x === 'apple'));
// ['apple', 'apple']
```

- You can use `find` to return first value of matched item or returned undefined if not found

```
const a = ['orange', 'apple', 'kiwi', 'apple'];
console.log(a.find(x => x === 'apple'));
// apple
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post something very important - I need it to work when I input even a part of what I need - eg. If if look for ap It will output apple